# how to fill a image with pattern

Tags: php, jquery, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

let's say i have a image !
[image]

now i want to fill that image with [image]

and my final image should look like this[image]

how to do it?
so far i was able to change the color of that image but was not able to fill pattern.

can i do it with html5 canvas (pattern)? is there any way to do it with php or any web platform.

Comment: you can't do this it easily,
but if you want to do it, i can't say about any library for image manipulation

make your second image a little transparent, and fill in area on first image, so the first images curve will shown as well but you have loose a little opacity.  

you can use magik, gd for php, and same thing apply for canvas but have to refer to its documetions about filing pattern

Comment: Use [PNGa and CSS](http://imgur.com/86fZO1i).

Comment: dear @SverriM.Olsen what is this "PNGa and CSS". can you provide the link of their site? google was not able to provide me an answer.

Comment: Using three layers might be the easiest, the image you have as the lowest, the pattern with opacity as the middle, and an overlay png in which the center in the same shape as the shirt image is empty ( transparent ) to provide a sort of clipping area. Creating an SVG with an image as a mask might be simpler though, in spite of the SVG learning curve. [W3C on SVG masking](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#Masking)

Comment: @MDTAHMIDHOSSAIN CSS is a browser language for styling websites. PNGa is an image format with transparency. Using CSS you can position a transparent image of the t-shirt above a background image (the pattern). If you have no idea what I am talking about then you have to learn a few things. This is quite basic stuff, and I do not have time to walk you through it.

Comment: dear @SverriM.Olsen thanks for ur reply and showing me the direction.

Comment: Use PNGa and CSS with layers, and its all game of opacity, you know

Comment: Dear @SverriM.Olsen can you give the code of http://imgur.com/86fZO1i

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Use these steps to create simulate applying a mapped pattern to your shirt:**

- Create a high-contrast version of your shirt.
- DrawImage that shirt onto the canvas
- Set globalCompositeOperation to “source-atop”
- (any new drawing will only appear where the shirt image is opaque)
- Create a pattern from your checkered image
- Fill the canvas with the checkered pattern
- (it will only appear in the non-transparent shirt)
- Set the globalAlpha to a very low value
- Repeatedly drawImage the high-contrast shirt
- (this effectively superimposes the shirt “wrinkles”)

[image]

**For a better solution**

Create a “bump-map” of the shirt and apply it with the checkered pattern in three.js

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/kzfKD/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img1=new Image();
    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){

        img1.onload=function(){
            start();
        }
        img1.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/4jiSz1.png";
    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/BooMu1.png";

    function start(){

        ctx.drawImage(img1,0,0);

        ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-atop";

        ctx.globalAlpha=.85;

        var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
        ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.globalAlpha=.15;
        ctx.drawImage(img1,0,0);
        ctx.drawImage(img1,0,0);

    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=436 height=567></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: by the way how do u created "bump-map" of the shirt? can i do it with jquery, html5 or i need to go back to photoshop?

Comment: Yes, create the texture map (bump map) in photoshop.

Comment: Texture maps and bump maps are two different things. For 2D *displacement* maps are better suited, for 3D normal maps and as a secondary bump maps.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments on your question, one approach is to overlay DOM elements -- the top DOM element should be a PNG with transparency, and the bottom one should be your background pattern. This also works (and it's faster since you don't have to compute the combined image) but provides a little less flexibility in terms of the way the images are combined. With the canvas method, you can use any blend mode you want.

A second option which is not supported by most browsers yet is to use [CSS background blend modes](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2013/06/24/css-background-blend-modes-are-now-available-in-chrome-canary-and-webkit-nightly/). This would allow you to create a PNG image with transparency, assign it a background color, and use blending with CSS. This is fast and only requires one DOM element.

A third approach is to use canvases. *(**Edit:** markE's canvas approach is faster and simpler.)* I implemented one canvas-based approach in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IceCreamYou/uzzLa/ -- here's the gist:

```
// Get the base image data
var image_data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
var image_data_array = image_data.data;

// Get the pattern image data
var overlay_data = ovlyCtx.getImageData(0, 0, ovlyCtx.canvas.width, ovlyCtx.canvas.height).data;

// Loop over the pixels in the base image and merge the colors
for (var i = 0, j = image_data_array.length; i < j; i+=4) {
    // Only merge when the base image pixel is nontransparent
    // Alternatively you could implement a border-checking algorithm depending on your needs
    if (image_data_array[i+3] > 0) {
        image_data_array[i+0] = combine(image_data_array[i+0], overlay_data[i+0]); // r
        image_data_array[i+1] = combine(image_data_array[i+1], overlay_data[i+1]); // g
        image_data_array[i+2] = combine(image_data_array[i+2], overlay_data[i+2]); // b
    }
}

// Write the image data back to the canvas
ctx.putImageData(image_data, 0, 0);
```

What it does is create one canvas with the base image and a second canvas that tiles your pattern image, then uses the pixel data to overlay the pattern over the base when the base pixels are nontransparent.